# Probability that a random bipartite graphs is the intersection of simple cycles

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I have the following problem and honestly i don't know how to start working on it. Any clue will be appreciated.

I need to calculate the probability that following the Erdos-Renyi model, a random bipartite graph $G(n,n,m)$ with exactly m=2n edges (each edge appears with probability $p$)  is the union of edge-disjoint simple cycles.

Any reference, clue or hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: so each edge appears with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: when you say disjoint cycles, you mean disjoint by vertices or edges ?

Comment: If it is the latter then Veblen's theorem seems useful.

Comment: Its edge-disjoint simple cycles and any fixed p. Thank you!